# When moving along the axis of a complex function why is the imaginary part level when the real part is steepest?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

**Background**: This is from the Method of Steepest Descent in Arfken et al, Mathematical Methods.

Starting with the Cauchy-Riemann formulas $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}$$
$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=-\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$$ 
Which as noted by Harald Hanche-Olsen are both zero at the saddle point.

Looking at the second order derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}=\frac{\partial\partial{v}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y^2}}=-\frac{\partial\partial{v}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$$
Adding we can get Laplace's equation: 
$$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y^2}}=0$$
Taking the opposite derivatives from above yields:
$$\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{y^2}}=0$$
Is there any intuitive way to see that there is a $45^{\circ}$ angle between the steepest descent of the real harmonic function and the steepest descent of the complex harmonic? (I see the $90^{\circ}$ difference between the steepest descent and greatest ascent within the same harmonic function easily.)

### [image]

Consider the taylor series of the function suggested (z^2) at the origin.

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed["[U(x,y)]", Center],  
PlotLabel -> Style["Re[Z^2]", Red, Large]]

ContourPlot[2 x y, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed["[V(x,y)]", Center],  
PlotLabel -> Style["Im[Z^2]", Red, Large]]
```

[image]
At the saddle point the function satisfies $f(z)=f_0 +\frac{1}{2}f"(z)(z-z_0)^2+O(z^3)$. Inserting $re^{i\theta_1}$ for $z-z_0$ and $C e^{i\theta_2}$ for f'' yields a real component of the series: 
$f(z)=f_0 +\frac{1}{2}Cr^2\cos(2\theta_1+\theta_2)+O(z^3)$. The second degree term is zero approached from four directions: $\theta_1=\frac{1}{2}(\pm\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta_2)$ and  $\frac{1}{2}(\pm\frac{3\pi}{2}-\theta_2)$. This shows that the level curves are $45^\circ$ from the direction of the steepest ascent of the real component $\theta_2$ divided by two. Did I do a calculation wrong since it should just be from the direction of $\theta_2$?. These level curves are purportedly the laplacian of the imaginary function v(x,y). Now for my question: I  don't understand why the level curves of the real function would correspond to the steepest curves of the imaginary at a saddle point. Here for instance the laplacian of the imaginary(2xy) is $V_{xx}+v_{yy}=0+0$ not $y=\pm x$. What is causing the level curve of V(x,y) to be the steepest curve of U(x,y)?

Comment: At a saddle point, the first order derivatives are zero, so you need to look at second order derivatives. Consider the origin for the function $z^2$ as the canonical example.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm going to edit my question to ask a new question now rather than deleting it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted my old question and now that has muddled things up. I'm referring to the saddle point where $f'(z)=0$ when using the method of steepest descent. At the critical point all the cauchy riemann equations will equal zero.